# Delete first DIV tag in a html document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have made a small chat box using JScript, php and jquery. The chat box content is stored in a HTML document that is echoed into the text area. Each message a user types is stored in a new div tag:

```
<div>Message</div>
<div>Second msg</div>
```

How do I remove the first div tag, when there are 50+ messages or the file size > 10kb (So that I don't use all the bandwidth)?

Comment: Stackoverflow doesn't do your work for you. What have you tried?

Comment: So you are storing the conversation in an html file instead of a database? And you need to manipulate the html file?

Comment: How does removing the tag after it's been sent to the client have any impact on the amount of bandwidth used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
$('div:first').remove()
```

With check

```
if ($('div').length) > 50) {
    $('div:first').remove();
}
```

Comment: I am curious to know if the .first() function is faster than the :first selector.